# convert a set into string in python

Tags: python, set

let say I got a set call x

```
x = set(['x','c','v','x','w','g'])

print(', '.join(x)
```

I get

```
x,c,v,x,w,g
```

How can modify my code to get

```
x,c,v,x,w or g
```

change the last , to a or?

Comment: How you get two `x` while operating in `set`?

Comment: Since you have two x's in your OP, you don't need set() rather this will work: `x = ['x','c','v','x','w','g']` ... `','.join(x[:-1])+' or '+x[-1]` ... `'x,c,v,x,w or g''`

Comment: typing error,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
print(', '.join(x[:-1]) + " or " + x[-1])
```

Comment: I don't think you can slice sets.

Comment: You can't slice sets, you need to cast it back to list, pop the last member, join the rest with a comma and add the last member with an 'or'